# Translation of an argument in logical notation.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, higher-order-logic

I have to formulate the following argument into logical notation :

**All accused are guilty.All who are convicted will hang.Therefore if all who are guilty are convicted then all the accused will hang.**

Which I translated like this :

The premises are :

($\forall x)(Ax \rightarrow Gx)$.

($\forall x)(Cx \rightarrow Hx)$.

The conclusion is:

($\forall x)(Gx \rightarrow Cx) \rightarrow ((\forall y)(Ay \rightarrow Hy))$.

Is it a right translation ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems okay to me. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @HirenGarai Hit the link under the answer to accept it.

Comment: I have a question regarding this, what if someone translates it like ($\forall x)((Gx \rightarrow Cx) \rightarrow ((\forall y)(Ay \rightarrow Hy)))$.,will it be wrong ? @Shaun ?

Comment: Yes . $~(\forall x~P(x))~\to~(\forall y~Q(y))~$ is not equivalent to $~\forall x~(P(x)\to \forall y~Q(y))~$, which is equivalent to $~(\exists x~P(x))~\to~(\forall y~Q(y))~$.